# Skip or ignore JavaScript error (on page third-party JS) in Phantom JS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Consider the code below:

```
var steps = [];
var testindex = 0;
var testError = 0;
var loadInProgress = false; 
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false; 
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

steps = [

    //Step 1 - Open  site
    function() {

        console.log('Step 1 - Open UK site');
        page.open("http://www.example.com/", function(status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log("Adidas UK is loading for long");
            }

        });

    },
function() {
        console.log('Step 2 - Search for the product');
        page.evaluate(function(login, password) {
            bla bla bla ...
        });

    },  
function() {
        bla bla ...

    },  
many more functions ...

//Execute steps one by one
interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep, 50);

function executeRequestsStepByStep() {
    if (loadInProgress == false && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        //console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("Script is completed...");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {

    var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

    if (trace && trace.length) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function+'")' : ''));
        });
    }
    console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
    phantom.exit(2); //this is needed in case any error related to phantom script occurs.

};
```

In the above code example, when i execute the script i get error something like this in Step 1 and Step 5 which is caused by some javascript code execution on the page at a point of time.

```
ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'sf_chat_Widget.loc
ale.includes("CH")')
TRACE:
 -> https://e-com.secure.force.com/adidasContact/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?fi
le=01520000003gdry: 58 (in function "loadWidget")
 -> http://www.adidas.co.uk/: 3367 (in function "onload")

  phantomjs://code/UkScript.js:158 in onError
```

I wish to ignore or skip this error without halting the execution of steps in script and only catch such errors caused by phantom JS script which is not happening and throwing all errors occurred on page.

> Is there already a way to skip or ignore specific on page error and
>   just catch errors happened in phantom js script?

P.S. I'm new to Stackoverflow when it comes to asking a question so if you find anything irrelevant or it is already been asked before please don't hesitate to fire.
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `window.onerror = function() { /* relax */ }`;

Comment: why not using a try catch around  steps[testindex](); ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question (probably) but just wondering-- what was the reasoning behind calling each step in rapid succession with `setInterval`, as opposed to setting up a promise or callback chain so that a step could fire asynchronously on the completion of the previous step?

Comment: @anied the reason behind using `setinterval` is each steps is opening and doing some action on page and then navigating to next page(step) and so on. The whole script is for an ecom website for example.

Comment: @logar i tried using try catch around steps but doesn't work, seems like `page.onerror()` method of phantomjs is surpassing any other error handling mechanism.

Comment: @MehulMohan can you provide an example? i tried using the same but not working?

Comment: @JayKay -- to be honest, I'm not completely following your reasoning, but if you're confident that this is the correct approach, and already considered a promise/callback based solution but found a compelling reason it was not the correct approach, then I'm satisfied.

Comment: @anied I'm not able to understand your concept of promise/callback may be because i barely work on javascript and would you mind sharing an example of this?
would this approach allow me to ignore or skip the specific error and continue navigating till checkout page?

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) allow you to chain steps in an asynchronous way. Ex `doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)` -- by returning promises from your function, you can chain in other functions that will only call after the first function resolves the promise-- thus no need for complex/fragile timers handling your step-wise logic.  [Callbacks](http://callbackhell.com/) are a similar concept but executed differently.